# After upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 I don't have ethernet connection, how to solve it?

Tags: networking, upgrade, ethernet

I had a wired network connection that worked fine in Ubuntu 11.10.

I upgraded to 12.04 and immediately after the upgrade was completed, the OS reported my **cable unplugged**.

It was not unplugged and was not defective.

I have a D-link DFE-530TXS 10/100 ethernet NIC and I see what seems to be the generic 10050 driver loaded.

Is there any way to just flush anything and everything to do with the network configuration and have Ubuntu reset/find everything again?

If not, is there any way, I can get it to realize that my network cable is not unplugged?  (considering it worked mere minutes before).

Comment: I assume you formerly used a different driver. Does the additional drivers program offer a familiar driver? Logs to check include /var/log/syslog and the udev log under the /var/log/ tree as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds crazy, but:

1. How are the LEDs on the physical connection? Nearly all have leds, and if no LEDs are present typically the cord/instantiating end are at fault.
2. If LEDs are present- are they "solid" or blinking?
3. If Solid? Probably a driver or hardware issue. Replace the hardware and troubleshoot. (frys electronics has a 15-day return policy. Just saying.)
4. If Blinking? Must be driver/configuration related. Post a relevantly  censored printout of the command:

   ifconfig -a

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on the latest 12.04 upgrade (I was already on 12.04, but an innocent-looking system update killed it).

Do you have settings for your interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` ? I have. This link may help: http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Wired_Networks_are_Unmanaged

In the end I un-installed Network Manager and it allows the standard `/etc/network/interfaces` stuff to work properly.